# Selecting multiple tables in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

Im new working with SQL. Actually I am working with SQLite and in my DB I have multiple tables. In my case I have 2 tables which should be shown as options. One is shown but the other one I don't know how to access it.

This is what I have now but I want to add another one. So instead "clients" will be "types"

How can I access the other table in the same time?

```
$sql = "SELECT 'i'.*,
            't'.'name' AS 'client_name'
            FROM 'items' 'i'
            JOIN 'clients' 't'
            ON 't'.'id' = 'i'.'client'
            ORDER BY 'i'.'date' ASC";
$sql = "SELECT *
            FROM 'clients'
            ORDER BY 'id'";
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the [correct delimiters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)?

Comment: Use join if those having Primary , foreign key relationship else use 2 query variables.

Comment: what do you mean? Now I can see the clients table data. If I change the details instead client_name to type_name or clients to types is showing only types table data. But what I want is to select both tables. Because I need to show on 2 option attribute as Clients: {{array}} and Types: {{array}}

Comment: Why is this tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sqlite]?